# How to execute windows command one by one using java process

Tags: java

I have a requirement to check DNS configuration using nslookup command. The proper way to check has been given in the following link.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997324(v=exchg.65).aspx

Now the actual problem in java is how to execute the commands one by one in the same process and I have to capture the output and based upon the output I may have to execute some other commands. The screenshot is given below.

[image: Screenshot given below]

It is easy to execute a simple command like "nslookup someIpAdrs". But here the requirement is different. First of all we have to enter the shell and in the same shell, I have to execute commands.

Please suggest me about how to do in Java processBuilder or if there is any java library to achieve.

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Comment: I have already gone through those sites. The requirement is not similar, it is different here. First apply the command "nslookup", you will get a shell. Then in that shell execute different types of commands and capture the output and then execute other commands.

Answer (score 3):

You need to open a new `PrintWriter` with the Process that executed your original command and print your arguments there.

For Example:

```
final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nslookup");
final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
final char[] buf = new char[20];
System.out.println(new String(buf, 0, in.read(buf)));
//Send next command here
new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream(),true).println(<next command>);
```

You can then flush the buffer and read the output thereafter.